# Quartz wait for a set of jobs to finish

Tags: mapreduce, quartz.net

We have a quatz job that does a lot of calculations and is taking a while to complete.  In order to speed it up we want to split the primary job to start multiple smaller jobs that do the calculations and return the result.  After all the small jobs complete we need a final job that will pull the subtotals together.

Currently the idea is each small job will write to a store, and when creating the final job we pass in all small job names to it with MapData.  The final job will look for these jobs and reschedule if any are found, else it will run the totals.

Is there a better way to accomplish this in quartz?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily answering the question, but I'm afraid I don't think Quartz is the tool for the job here. It's a scheduler, not a mechanism for load balancing. You could look at using Quartz in combination with NServiceBus or MassTransit. The job could fire multiple messages for the small jobs, maybe even using the same message type and a [Distributor](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/) and use a [Saga](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) to pull everything back together.